# In Microsoft Azure , what is the difference between Azure AD device and MSOL device

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I was trying to find out all the devices synchronized with Azure AD from On-premises AD, while searching I came accross two powershell commands **Get-AzureADDevice** and **Get-MsolDevice**. What is the difference between these two commands.

Answer (score 1):

`Get-AzureADDevice` is part of the new module and should be used whenever possible. Some scenarios might not yet be available, e.g. [LifeCycle management](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21519)

http://get-cmd.com/?p=5445

> MSOnline
>
> The MSOnline Module, with its *-MSOL* cmdlets, was the first Windows PowerShell Module for Azure Active Directory. Microsoft refers to this module as version 1.0. MSOnline is the old module, which can still provide functionality that is not yet available in the AzureAD module. Probably, the MSOnline module will be deprecated when all of the functionality has been migrated to the newer module called AzureAD.
>
> AzureAD
>
> Its full name is Azure Active Directory PowerShell for Graph. Microsoft refers to this module as version 2.0. The AzureAD module, and its dependencies, can be installed and updated using PowerShellGet from the PowerShell Gallery.
>
> Microsoft recommends to use the newer AzureAD module.